# Check whether filtered values per group in other column exist in equal number of times, then calculate time difference based on precedence

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the trouble on cleaning the data like below, I want for each distinct value in **Name** column filter only those record in **Country** which has either **Y** or **Z**. and check whether those **Y** and **Z** appears equal number of time for each distinct value in **Name** column. If both values are in equal pairs then raised the flag for that specific **Name** value. As Y occur before Z so want to pick the highest value in time of Y for that **Name** and Lowest Value of **Z** in **Date** and **Time**. Calculate the difference in time and record in separate column called as Exposure Time.

| Date | Time | Country | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/1/2022 | 5:01 AM | X | Ehsan |
| 14/1/2022 | 4:01 AM | Y | Ehsan |
| 14/1/2022 | 3:05 AM | Y | Ehsan |
| 14/1/2022 | 4:05 AM | Y | Ayesha |
| 14/1/2022 | 9:05 AM | Z | Ayesha |
| 15/2/2022 | 10:05 AM | X | Zohan |
| 15/2/2022 | 10:08 AM | X | Mirha |
| 15/2/2022 | 04:03 AM | X | Mirha |
| 15/2/2022 | 05:04 PM | Y | Mirha |
| 15/2/2022 | 05:08 PM | Z | Mirha |

Below is the desired output result:

| Date | Time | Country | Name | Flag | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/1/2022 | 3:05 AM | Y | Ehsan | 0 |  |
| 14/1/2022 | 4:01 AM | Y | Ehsan | 0 |  |
| 14/1/2022 | 4:05 AM | Y | Ayesha | 1 |  |
| 14/1/2022 | 9:05 AM | Z | Ayesha | 1 | 5 hrs |
| 15/2/2022 | 05:04 PM | Y | Mirha | 1 |  |
| 15/2/2022 | 05:08 PM | Z | Mirha | 1 | 4 Mins |

Comment: So you need only those rows which has Country value as `Y, Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#filtered only Y an Z rows
df1 = df[df['Country'].isin(['Y','Z'])].copy()
#helper column with datetimes
df1['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'] + ' ' + df1['Time'], dayfirst=True)

print (df1)

#extract maximal datetimes per Y rows
df2 = df1.loc[df1[df1['Country'].eq('Y')].groupby('Name')['datetime'].idxmax()]
print (df2)

#extract minimal datetimes per Z rows
df3 = df1.loc[df1[df1['Country'].eq('Z')].groupby('Name')['datetime'].idxmin()]
print (df3)


#get difference of maximal and minimal datetimes
diff = df3.set_index('Name')['datetime'].sub(df2.set_index('Name')['datetime'])
#if some negative values (order Z, Y) remove it
diff = diff[diff.dt.total_seconds().gt(0)]
print (diff)

#mapping difference only for rows with Z
df1['diff'] = df1['Name'].map(diff).where(df1['Country'].eq('Z'),None)
#if match at least one value is 1 else 0
df1['flag'] = df1['Name'].isin(df1.loc[df1['diff'].notna(), 'Name']).astype(int)

#sorting per Names and datetimes
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Name','datetime'])
```

---

```
print (df1)
        Date      Time Country    Name            datetime            diff  \
3  14/1/2022   4:05 AM       Y  Ayesha 2022-01-14 04:05:00             NaT   
4  14/1/2022   9:05 AM       Z  Ayesha 2022-01-14 09:05:00 0 days 05:00:00   
2  14/1/2022   3:05 AM       Y   Ehsan 2022-01-14 03:05:00             NaT   
1  14/1/2022   4:01 AM       Y   Ehsan 2022-01-14 04:01:00             NaT   
8  15/2/2022  05:04 PM       Y   Mirha 2022-02-15 17:04:00             NaT   
9  15/2/2022  05:08 PM       Z   Mirha 2022-02-15 17:08:00 0 days 00:04:00   

   flag  
3     1  
4     1  
2     0  
1     0  
8     1  
9     1
```

Comment: He himself would have been able to do it, had he understood the problem completely. Its basically filter on values `Y, Z`

Comment: Actually i want for each distinct value in Name column , i have to check that that there are equal number of pairs for Country . I meant to say that for Ehsan there are equal number of Y and Z present or Not for each Name.

Comment: For Example if i had the Ehsan then if Y is 15 times and Z should also be 15 times. I meant to say that Y and Z are dependent on each other if one exist other must exist. If it is the case then after sorting the result with respect to Time ,

Comment: i have to pick the highest value of time for Y  (As in time Y always occur befor Z)and Lowest value of Time for Z and See the difference in Time. That difference should be in seperate column. I am hoping you understand it Let me re-edit the question please

Comment: @Ehsan125 - Now understand more, so if 2 times `Z` and two times `Y` is filtered group because same count? If 1xZ, 2xY then not? Or then 1xY and 1xZ ? The best should be change data sample

Comment: @Ehsan125 - answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael i have edited the question. Please see, Thank you so much for your previous ansers.

Comment: @Ehsan125 - `nd check whether those Y and Z appears equal number of time for each distinct value in Name column.` - it means only once per group? If multiple times can you add some sample to question?

Comment: @Ehsan125 - `As Y occur before Z` - whats happens if not `Y before Z`? Whats happens if multiple times `Y, Z` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes , you interpreted very well, that per group of distinct value in name the number of Y and Z should be equal. if not raised the flag as 0 otherwise 1 as shown in question.

Comment: The mostly cases which i have seen in the dataset the z only happens after y. or i would say you may take the anology of on/off switch. If you have turned on the switch then off would also exist. And ON will always Followed by Off.

Comment: @Ehsan125 - So if order `Z Y` then flag is `0` ? If order `Y Z` flag is `1` ? But whats happens if 2x Y and 2x Z like in edited answer? How is possible use this logic?

Comment: @jezrael when you will sort the result with respect to time the y will never come after the z in the same group of distinct values. In the question i did not shown the actual number of times Y and Z appears per group but implicitly it could be indefinite number of time per group but it could be 15 time Y and 15 Times Z per group or any number of time but mostly both will appear equal number of times per group if not then we will raise the flag.

Comment: @Ehsan125 - so my EDIT solution is necessary filter if not equal Z and Y ? Or always same count per groups?

Comment: @jezrael same count per group and for each group check either number of y and Z are equal if not raise the flag. and see the time difference with in the group the time of last y and then time of very first z. and calculate the difference and record in seperate column. I think its now logical, right?

Comment: @jezrael dear sir, as you can see in Ehsan group there is no value of Z present so there are two y and 0 z, so we will flag it as 0, because one category y is present but not the z.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246188/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ehsan125).

Comment: @jezrael thank you sir for creating this chat.

Comment: @Ehsan125 - Answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael thank you , you are legend and pro sir.